# In SAS EG4.3, will you please let me know the option if it is available for "Enclose values within quotes" in prompt window for a character prompt

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

In SAS EG4.3, will you please let me know the option if it is available for "Enclose values within quotes" in prompt window for a character prompt.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

How are you using your prompt? It you filter by it, you can force the filter to surround your prompt with quotes. Just tick "Enclose the value in quotes" and make sure you have unticked "Generate filter for a prompt value"

The screenshot is for SAS EG 5.1, but 4.3 has exactly the same functionality/interface if memory serves me right.

[image: example]

I hope it helps, 
Vasilij

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure; 4.3 was quite "young" in the EG development cycle.  But hopefully this is sufficient for the OP to  figure out if the option is there or not.

Comment: I have aceess to SAS EG 4.1 and the option is already there, I can't image it got taken out for 4.3. Anyway, leave a note here if it worked or mark the question as answered once you had something back from your users.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure of what you are asking but you may try these:
1. Double click the column to unlock it and then change the type to character if that is the requirements.
OR
2. if you need to enclose values inside double quotes (for example: "name") then you may try in query builder the CATT/CATX functions

```
CATT("""t.name""")
```

hope it helps.

Comment: This does not answer the question as asked.  The OP is asking about prompts, not about dataset variables.

Comment: it would be nice of you if you not look down upon people's answers by marking negative when they are trying to help. there is no need to discourage knowledge sharing. :)

Comment: The answer does not answer the question.  As such it receives a downvote. Answers on SO are expected to be specific to the question; if you are unsure of what the question asks please leave a comment.